# Redis subscribe is quicker than publish?

Tags: php, performance, redis, publish-subscribe

There are two scripts at one sever, redis at localhost.

Script 1:

```
$redis = new Redis();
$redis->connect($redisHost, $redisPort);

while (1) {
    $redis->publish('test-tt', microtime(true));
}
```

Script 2:

```
$redis = new Redis();
$redis->connect($redisHost, $redisPort);

$result = $redis->subscribe(['test-tt'], '_redis_processor');

function _redis_processor($redis, $channel, $message) {
    print number_format(microtime(true) - $message, 12)."\n";
}
```

Execution results:

```
 0.000058889389
 0.000087022781
 0.000006198883
 0.000027179718
 0.000051021576
 0.000074148178
-0.000004053116
 0.000016927719
 0.000045061111
 0.000064849854
-0.000011920929
 0.000020027161
 0.000045061111
 0.000066041946
-0.000012159348
 0.000011920929
 0.000033855438
 0.000057935715
 0.000082015991
 0.000101089478
 0.000140905380
 0.000092983246
```

Why sometimes timings are < 0?

Comment: Is this _really_ all the code there is? How are you executing it? Have you tried replicating the results with `hrtime(true)`?

Comment: Yes, it's all code. 
hrtime(true) works ok.
But I try to understand how microtime(true) can be less?

Comment: How are you executing it?

Comment: Please include any `require` or gem file code.